# Pinch to zoom on mapboxgl zooms in entire chrome window. How to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox-gl-js

I am using mapboxgl as a mapping inside of my website. When users attempt to zoom in using two fingers on a touchscreen, the map zooms in, but then the entire website zooms in too. How do I make it such that if user uses two fingers to zoom in on map, that it does not zoom in the entire webpage?

Comment: Do you have an example of this? And on which device? What you're describing is not normal.

Comment: PC, Microsoft Surface Book. 1/4th of the screen is a mapboxgl map, but it is surrounded by divs/bootstrap template.

Comment: running which browser? - IE Edge?

Comment: Latest Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when developing mapbox app for a windows10 kiosk. This can be fixed my specifying touch-action as none for mapbox container div.

```
#map{
    touch-action:none;
}
```